# How do I write a LaTeX file from a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, latex, monads, file-writing

OK so I have something that looks like this:

```
[Just [["Value1"],["","",""]],Just [["Value2"],["","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","Value3",""]],Just [["Value4","",""]],Just [["Value5"],["","",""]],Just [["Value6"],["","",""]],Just []]
```

and I need to write all of those values to a LaTeX file, ignoring the empty strings(possibly in pairs, one line per pair).

How would I go to do that?

Thanks

EDIT: My file should look like this:

```
 Value1 Value2
 Value3 Value4
 Value5 Value6
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. Maybe it would help if you added the expected output latex source file for your example?

Comment: Well my file should look like this:
Some String Some other value
 Again, some value  more values
Hey, a value a value appeared!

Or better said:
Value1 Value2
Value3 Value4
Value5 Value6

Comment: I just edited the question, it should make more sense now. Thanks

Comment: Your input has unbalanced list delimiters (`[` and `]`) and string delimiters (`"`), and the list (of lists?) containing "Value4" isn't a `Maybe [[String]]` like the others. Please ensure the input is valid and clarify what parts are relevant to the transformation you want.

Comment: Sorry that was my bad, I just fixed it. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Simplify your input to a `[String]` of the form `["Value1", "Value2", "Value3", "Value4", "Value5", "Value6"]`. The functions `catMaybes`, `concat`, `filter`, and `null` may be helpful.
2. Group your values into pairs. Depending on what you want, you may like to write this by hand or use [`chunksOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/split-0.2.3.1/docs/Data-List-Split.html#v:chunksOf) from the `split` package.
3. Combine pairs with `unwords`; combine sets of pairs with `unlines`.
4. Write to your file with `writeFile`.

Except where noted, all of these functions are in the standard library.